# Disable Windows Firewall popup for automated tests

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-8, automated-tests, windows-firewall

We are running automated tests from Visual Studio. Some of these tests needs to communicate with a temporary [Redis](http://redis.io/) server and we therefore launch `redis-server.exe` in a [JobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161(v=vs.85).aspx) during test execution.

The `redis-server.exe` executable file is deployed to the test run directory by declaring [`[DeploymentItem("redis-server.exe")]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute.aspx).

This works fine except that for every test run an annoying Windows Firewall popup is displayed:

[image]

**Is it possible to prevent this popup from being displayed?**

Would it, for example, be possible to tell Windows that any `redis-server.exe` located under a specific directory is allowed to use the network?

This is particularly annoying because the dialog fulfills no purpose in this case. No matter whether I choose to click on *Allow access* or *Cancel* or even just ignore the popup, the tests will still complete. However, a new firewall rule is created every time.

Comment: You can disable this popup entirely using group policy.  Or use `netsh` to create the firewall rule programmatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No idea if it's actually possible, but the best solution would be to change the listening settings on the temporary server so that it listens on 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0, causing it to only accept connections from the local machine. For a test it's perfectly acceptable, and such a listening will never trigger firewall warnings.

Comment: Simple and understandable, didn't know that there was a difference between 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is related to VisualStudio, but I had exactly the same problem, but with *Intellij* and *Java*.

In *Java*, it is possible to configure the server like in the following piece of code to achieve the same thing (no firewall warning being displayed):

`RedisServer.builder().setting("bind 127.0.0.1")...build()`

The trick is the setting value `"bind 127.0.0.1"`.

With this configuration no more firewall warning appears.

I found the answer in the embedded-redis project on GitHub ([here](https://github.com/kstyrc/embedded-redis/issues/45#issuecomment-116592376)).